# Passing BufferedInputStream to a method that accepts InputStream

Tags: java, groovy, inputstream, metadata-extractor

I am calling a method that accepts `InputStream`. Here is the method on github: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/2.8.0/Source/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.java#L89

I am calling the method with `BufferedInputStream` which should work since it is a child of `InputStream` but I keep getting this error:

```
No signature of method: static com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedInputStream) values: [java.io.BufferedInputStream@74d4ec5f]
Possible solutions: readMetadata(java.io.File), readMetadata(java.io.BufferedInputStream, boolean). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: static com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedInputStream) values: [java.io.BufferedInputStream@74d4ec5f]
Possible solutions: readMetadata(java.io.File), readMetadata(java.io.BufferedInputStream, boolean)
    Line | Method
->>  137 | settings  in com.foo.scanner.AdminController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     59 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
```

Here is my code:

```
println file62.name //prints name of the file
println file62.inputStream.getClass() //prints java.io.BufferedInputStream
InputStream is = (InputStream)file62.inputStream
Metadata metadata = com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(is) //readMetadata expects InputStream
```

Version of the library I have:

`✗ grails dependency-report | grep  "drew"
+--- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1
+--- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1
+--- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1`

and this is the method in 2.9.1: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/2.9.1/Source/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.java#L88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception says that the method is expecting either a `File`, or a `BufferedInputStream` *and* a boolean. There is no overload that expects *only* a `BufferedInputStream`.

If you're sure that the formal parameters and the actual parameters match, then the most likely reason for this sort of exception (caused by a formal parameter mismatch) is that there is an old jar lying around. Run `mvn clean`, `gradle clean`, check your web container's lib directory, and generally eliminate errant jars from your system.

Comment: The github link says that the method expects `InputStream`. Can I not pass `BufferedInputStream` where `InputStream` is expected?

Comment: You can. But the exception disagrees with github. Have you got a different version of the jar?

Comment: I'm browsing the history of the file. The method used to take an `InputStream` but no longer does. Looks like you've got a newer jar than 2.8.0.

Comment: no. I have the right version. I am updating the question

Comment: Looks good. But the exception clearly states `No signature of method: static com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedInputStream) values: [java.io.BufferedInputStream@74d4ec5f]`, `Possible solutions: readMetadata(java.io.File), readMetadata(java.io.BufferedInputStream, boolean)`. Is this happening in a web container? Does it also happen in a simple integration tests outside of a container? Have a look for older versions of the jar in your web container's lib or etc dir. BTW Are you using Tomcat? JBoss? ...?

Comment: >_< ended up a jar in lib folder. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

@PaulHicks was exactly right. The API you were calling into was misguided and removed with extreme prejudice back in 2012, with this commit:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/commit/9f3854b81313f1ea498b991d36253f221db79dca#diff-8fa1b864bada9112be69ec00784af715

GitHub suggests that API was removed in version 2.7.0.